# mysql_upgrade not found

Tags: mysql, linux

I've just upgrade my system, but Mysql don't start:

```
120319 15:20:39 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120319 15:20:39 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120319 15:20:39  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
120319 15:20:39  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120319 15:20:39  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43665
120319 15:20:39 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory
120319 15:20:39 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?
120319 15:20:39 [ERROR] Aborting
```

so I am asked to run myslq_upgrade, but it's not present on the system...

Any help?

Comment: did you check in the same exactly bin folder of mysql ?

Comment: Which Distribution you are using?

Comment: mysql_upgrade is a binary comes with `mysql-server-core` package. 
Try re-installing `mysql-server-core`. The package name might be different in your distro.

Comment: I am using debian squeeze, and I've made a dist-upgrade

Comment: and trying to resintall mysql-server-core does not made any change, mysql_upgrade still missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to manually remove some of the package, rename old database and configuration file, reinstall things and it worked, but still no mysql_upgrade....

Anyway, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I found that on Amazon Linux 1 AMI it was installed but wasn't in the PATH. I did a `sudo find / -type f -name mysql_upgrade` and it was in `/usr/libexec/mysql55/mysql_upgrade`.